# PayPal Sandbox Invoice Paid but stays in SENT status

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am testing out the payment of an invoice in the PayPal sandbox environment.

I use the API to create and send the invoice.  The status shows as SENT.  I click the link returned by the `/send` method to open an view the invoice.  It opens up as expected in my browser in the Sandbox environment.  I click on the "Pay" link, and a popup window opens and I process a credit card payment.

However, when I then query the status of the invoice in the API, it remains in SENT status.  Should this not advance to PAID?

Also, I have configured the INVOICES.INVOICE.PAID webhook as well as the PAYMENT.AUTHORIZATION.CREATED webook, but neither of them fired when payment was made.

Can anyone tell me what I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was that I had to use a specific credit card defined for the account in the Sandbox environment.  Once that was done, all processed as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Does the receiving account have a confirmed email identifier within the sandbox environment?

- Check and resend any confirmation message within https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/businessprofile/settings/email
- Read any confirmation message and follow its link and steps, via https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fnotifications%2F

If that's not the issue, you'll need to post more detailed information of the responses you're getting.